# Can you monitor button press of Bluetooth controller in Windows 10 using Python?

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been trying to monitor the button presses of a Bluetooth Xbox controller using [`bleak`](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (in Python 3, on Windows 10). I switched to `bleak` after finding that `pybluez` is not able to handle BLE devices on Windows, which my controller seems to be.

However, I'm running into three problems.

1. I can't find a mac address of my controller on Windows. I've looked at `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`, and right-clicked *Xbox Wireless Controller* to then go to *Properties>Connected Device*, but it says the mac address is unavailable, and the unique identifier that is listed never works as a string argument to `BleakClient`. I believe my controller changes mac address every once and a while, and that changing address is the only thing that is read by `bleak`.
2. There are a variable number of devices when I use `await BleakScanner.discover()`. I can't figure out why devices sometimes show up and sometimes don't. Also, the wait is so long sometimes that I've tried the `timeout` parameter, but it has even worse output dependability (e.g., sometimes never discovers any devices).
3. I can't seem to get any Bluetooth device to connect in `bleak` at all. The code below never finds a successful connection with any Bluetooth device, controller or otherwise, on my computer. I thought maybe I had to insert the `pair()` method before the `connect()` method, but I always get the same error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'device_information'`

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient, exc

## Get all devices

async def run():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    controllers = [BleakClient(d) for d in devices]
    for c in controllers:
        try:
            await c.connect()
            print(f"address: {c.address}, is_connected: {c.is_connected}")
        except (exc.BleakError):
            print(f"{c.address} failed from Bleak error.")
        except (asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError, asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError):
            print(f"{c.address} failed from asyncio error.")
            

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

I'd love help on any one of these problems, or a recommended alternative package that would work for Python + Windows + Bluetooth controller.

Comment: There are two types of Bluetooth; "Classic" and "BLE". An xbox control uses "Classic" and Bleak is for "BLE" so it will not work. Sorry don't have any recommendation for using on Windows but searching for "python xbox controller windows" brought up a number of alternative libraries when I did a search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ukBaz. However, I think it is a BLE device. The model of the controller is called "Bluetooth LE Device" in its properties. Also: "The newer Series Controllers (and older controllers with the newest firmware update) use BLE rather than "Classic" Bluetooth as it is called." (link [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/t2749r/comment/hyl20sv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)).

Comment: Also, I agree that there seem to be options for wired xbox controllers (e.g., the [`inputs`](https://pypi.org/project/inputs/0.3/) package), but unless I'm wrong, I don't believe they work for bluetooth connections. I was hoping to get this working for a bluetooth-connected controller, and the number of helpful search results plummet when I search "python windows bluetooth xbox controller".

Comment: Actually I finally got around to trying the inputs package and it works great and has a much simpler interface. I'll use that instead.